# How to log AJAX Errors with Log4J

Tags: java, ajax

Is there a way to catch errors from an AJAX request and log them in backend with Log4J?
Adding a console.log to my JS is not an option. I really need my AJAX errors logged along with my application log in server side.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: What kind of AJAX errors?

Comment: If you have log4j properly configured on your application, the error will be logged.

Comment: @christopher: thanks for your reply. Please check my answer to Patrick Grimard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to log client side errors to the server.  Can you clarify?

Using Log4J in your application, you can log errors and exceptions on the server side.  So assuming an AJAX request that produces an error on the client also produces an error on the server, you could log that, but you can't log a client/browser side error on your server unless you wrote some client side logic that also sends the error information back to the server in another request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Patrick. I have a AJAX code sending requests to services that are out of my control for they are from others. Sometimes I get error code 400 when doing that, which reflects in an error message to users. I want a way to log that in my application logs so I could document how frequently it occurs. Does it make sense?

Comment: If you don't have access to the web service on the server, then you won't be able to log the messages yourself.  Anything that happens in the client will remain in the client.